# The type or namespace "OpenGLEventArgs" could not be found

Tags: c#

I am new to 3D graphics so i was following the instructions from the site of our university on how  to work with 3D graphics  but i can't understand why i have this error and if it's possible  can someone explain to me how to fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
        {
            var gl = args.OpenGL;
            gl.ClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
        }
        private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
        {
            var gl = args.OpenGL;
            gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_TRIANGLES);
            gl.Color(0f, 1f, 0f);
            gl.Vertex(-1f, -1f);
            gl.Vertex(0f, 1f);
            gl.Vertex(1f, -1f);
            gl.End();
        }
        private void OpenGLControl_Resized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include the namespace.

Comment: What library are you using for OpenGL? I don't see anything referenced in your `using` directives that would provide that

Comment: Looks like you need to add `using SharpGL.SceneGraph;`?

Comment: UnholySheep these using directives were put there automatically when i made the project. I seriously don't have any idea what are they supposed to do because i have just started programming with 3D . I am a complete amateur.

Comment: By the way DavidG thanks  for the information that helped but now i have another problem it says that OpenGL does not exist in the current context  in lines 36 and 37

Comment: Then you probably also need a `using SharpGL;` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two key imports to be able to use the [`SharpGL`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpGL/) library. Just add these lines:

```
using SharpGL;
using SharpGL.SceneGraph;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles across this:

The issue here is that there are different versions of SharpGL. From the namespace, I'm assuming the OP wants to use the WPF version.

We need to add:

```
using SharpGL;
using SharpGL.WPF;
```

And also the event args parameters are slightly different:

```
private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLRoutedEventArgs args)
...
private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw(object sender, OpenGLRoutedEventArgs args)
```

I.e. use **OpenGLRoutedEventArgs** rather than **OpenGLEventArgs**.